# ScreenRecord command programmatically in Android 4.4

Tags: android

I was trying to record the screen programmatically using the following code:

```
private class SuTask extends AsyncTask<Boolean, Void, Boolean> {
    private final byte[] mCommand;

    public SuTask(byte[] command) {
        super();
        this.mCommand = command;
    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Boolean... booleans) {
        try {
            Process sh = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su", null, null);
            OutputStream outputStream = sh.getOutputStream();
            outputStream.write(mCommand);
            outputStream.flush();
            outputStream.close();

            final NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) mContext
                    .getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            notificationManager.notify(RUNNING_NOTIFICATION_ID,
                    createRunningNotification(mContext));

            sh.waitFor();
            return true;

        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(mContext,"error",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(mContext,"error",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        return false;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean bool) {
        super.onPostExecute(bool);
        if (bool) {
            final NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) mContext
                    .getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            notificationManager.cancel(RUNNING_NOTIFICATION_ID);

            File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() 
                    + "/recording.mp4");
            notificationManager.notify(FINISHED_NOTIFICATION_ID,
                    createFinishedNotification(mContext, file));

        }

    }

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    private Notification createRunningNotification(Context context) {
        Notification.Builder mBuilder = new Notification.Builder(
                context)
                .setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.stat_notify_sdcard)
                .setContentTitle(
                        context.getResources().getString(
                                R.string.app_name))
                .setContentText("Recording Running")
                .setTicker("Recording Running")
                .setPriority(Integer.MAX_VALUE).setOngoing(true);

        return mBuilder.build();
    }

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    private Notification createFinishedNotification(Context context,
            File file) {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), "video/mp4");

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
                context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        Notification.Builder mBuilder = new Notification.Builder(
                context)
                .setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.stat_notify_sdcard)
                .setContentTitle(
                        context.getResources().getString(
                                R.string.app_name))
                .setContentText("Recording Finished")
                .setTicker("Recording Finished")
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent).setOngoing(false)
                .setAutoCancel(true);

        return mBuilder.build();
    }
}
```

I am calling this AsyncTask in a Button onclicklistener:

```
StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder(
                        "/system/bin/screenrecord");
               /**
                    stringBuilder.append(" --size ")
                            .append("400").append("x")
                            .append("400");
                    stringBuilder.append(" --bit-rate ").append("20");
                    stringBuilder.append(" --time-limit ").append("180");*/

                // TODO User definable location.
                stringBuilder
                        .append(" ")
                        .append(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()).append("/recording.mp4");
                Log.d("TAG", "comamnd: " + stringBuilder.toString());
                Log.d("TAG", "PATH: " + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory());
                try {
                    new SuTask(stringBuilder.toString().getBytes("ASCII"))
                            .execute();

                } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Log.e("TAG", "error: " + e.getMessage());
                }
```

But when I run it, the notification says "Running" then just after a few seconds it says "Finished". When I click the notification, it says it cant play the video. I also verified the video file in the SD CARD if its there, but there's no video file there.

I will be very thankful to those people who can help me now.

UPDATE: I tried running the screenrecord from the command prompt and it works. But when I install other screen recording apps in my phone to test if its working I always get the error: Make sure sd card is not locked/unwritable.

Comment: There are issues with writing to external SD card since kitkat came out. 
Have you tried saving to the internal memory? Once that works, you should take time to read the documentation and find the right way to save stuff in the external storage. 
Sorry but I can't help you more than this :)

Comment: @FrancescoMapelli Will I use this `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` ?